# Is the canonical decomposition of $1$ defined?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is the canonical decomposition of $1$ defined ?

Many theorem starts by: let $m$ be a positive integer with  canonical decomposition $p_1^{e_1} \dots p_n^{e_n}$.

Sometimes I don't see the proof quite fit if $e_i = 0 \ \ \forall \ i$, also the canonical decomposition of $1$ is not unique, which is the case for all other positive integers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clean" definition is that the canonical decomposition of $1$ is the empty product, i.e., the product of no factors.  This maintains the main features of the canonical decompositions of larger integers: The set of primes in the decomposition is uniquely determined; all of the exponents are positive integers.

Of course, this definition presupposes that you've adopted the right definition of the product of no factors, namely that it equals $1$, but you should adopt that definition anyway, to make lots of other formulas work out cleanly.

Comment: For example how is the Jacobi symbol defined for $m = 1$ ?

Comment: I assume your $m$ is supposed to be the "bottom" number in the Jacobi symbol.  When this $m$ equals $1$, the usual definition makes $(\frac a1)$ equal to the empty product, hence equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you. You are probably right even thus it is not stated explicit in my book regarding the Jacobi symbol and $m=1$.